# Android JNI DefineClass Equivelent (Loading Classes)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am in JNI code, and I have a `.class` file, which I want to dynamically load and use as a `jclass`.  This is normally done by calling `env->DefineClass(...)` but that appears to be removed in the Android JNI, as it prompts me with:

```
JNI DefineClass is not supported
```

Which makes sense based on the implementation: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/jni/jni_internal.cc#665

I don't see anything online discussing how to actually get this functionality from the JNI, though.  What mechanism can I use to dynamically load Java classes from the JNI?

Comment: You cannot. The Android runtime environment does not know about java class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.
The compilation process for Android applications turns Java .class files into a format called "DEX", which is baked into the APK.

There is no runtime functionality for loading additional DEX files.

Comment: Is there any mechanism to intercept calls or create other proxies for callbacks that you are aware of?  I am not sure how to generate appropriate callbacks for events that I would want to call?

Comment: Please edit your question (or ask a new one) with the actual problem you are trying to solve. You know about [java.lang

Comment: *Java.lang.Proxy

Comment: Wowhee! That might actually be the keyword needed to get me moving again!  Thank you so much for the pointer!